# How to open a new browser window on a different screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, google-chrome, multiple-monitors

I am using Window 8 with 2 screens main screen for Window is the right one.

On the **left** screen I have Google Chrome browser window **open**.

When use short-cut `CRTL + N` a new window is open on the left screen,

I need to open it instead on the right screen instead.

Basically I needto force the browser to open always any new window on the right screen.

At the moment I am dragging the window from one screen to another, I would like to know if there any hack, or solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

I have a workaround. Unfortunately, this does not answer your question directly. Perhaps someone will post a better answer.

---

**Option 1**

Go with your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> on Google Chrome, and then follow that up by <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>➡</kbd>. That'll move your window quickly to the other screen.

**Option 2**

Rather than open a new Google Chrome window and then navigate to a website, you could [create shortcuts for apps and websites](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710?hl=en) you frequently visit. Google Chrome will remember the position of the shortcut depending on where it was placed last.

Answer (score 1):

This works on Ubuntu with Chrome, based on where I got the information, it will work in Windows also.

1. Open Chrome (or any application)
2. Use the <kbd>Win</kbd> key (yes, even on ubuntu) with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> to move the application from one monitor to the next (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>) to get it to the monitor you want new windows to open in future.
3. Drag the window to the monitor where you want to have it normally.
   Now, when you first open Chrome (any application). It will open on the monitor you moved it to in step 2, so you'll need to drag it to the one where you want it normally, but all windows "opened in new window" will open on the other monitor.

e.g. I have a small monitor on my laptop (with camera), and a large monitor right of that. I'd like Chrome on the large monitor most of the time, but open meetings on the laptop (so I'm looking at the camera when looking at people). I open Chrome, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> to put it on the laptop, then drag it with the mouse to the monitor. Voila, Chrome is on my 2nd monitor, but whenever I open up a meeting, as long as I right click and open in a new window, it opens on the laptop.